# Preferred way to install Ruby/Rake for all users

Tags: ubuntu, ruby-on-rails, ruby

We have a few different servers setup to handle our flagship product. We have a development server, a demo/staging server, and a production server. All of these run on some variant of Debian or Ubuntu.

In order to manage the creation of new clients, compress backups, list statistical data, and whatnot; I created a new Git repository (hosted on [GitHub](http://github.com)) that contains a bunch of Rake tasks. I then used [rvm](http://beginrescueend.com/) to install Ruby and [bundler](http://gembundler.com/) to install the necessary gems, and I use `rvmsudo rake my_task` to execute the tasks.

This worked really well until I had a new developer join the project. He's having to download rvm, install ruby, and install all of the proper gems to get it to work, and it's been a pain for him to figure out whether to use `sudo` or `rvmsudo` because it's setup slightly differently on each machine.

So, I'm wanting to kinda start fresh and re-install everything on every server. Ideally, I want my developers to clone the Git repo to their home directory (in case they are modifying the rake tasks themselves) and execute rake tasks using sudo OR rvmsudo. I want to standardize it so that they don't have to guess which one it is.

I remember having some trouble getting the latest versions of Ruby, Rails and Rake installed with the default `apt-get` package manager which is why I switched to using rvm, but it looks like that might have been a poor choice.

**So, does anyone know of a great guide or have any pointers on how to setup Ruby/Rails/Rake on a server so that all developers with sudo access can execute the commands and not have to worry about installing anything?**

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are taking the big first step in standardizing your environment.  Congratulations - You are in for a brief period of agony, followed by sysadmin Nirvana.
Seriously, take a month, build what you want your systems to look like for the foreseeable future, and start working on a plan to deploy that everywhere using some kind of deployment tool ([puppet](http://www.puppetlabs.com) or [chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/) are the most common these days).

---

Deployment tools and standardization solve your main problem: Everything will work the same way on every machine.

In terms of getting software onto the template machine and picking how things will work, my suggestion on a Debian-based system is to install everything using `apt` if you can, but if you're using deployment tools it isn't quite as critical: Your systems will be deployed, patched and maintained by the tools, so you shouldn't **EVER** be doing one-off patches on a live server. (Yeah, it happens sometimes, but remember that your deployment tools will stomp on those changes, so be sure that you make them the *right* way at some point.)

Be sure to give your developers a chance to play with the new environment (a VMWare lab is VERY nice to have) before you roll it out...

Comment: +1/Accepted - Thanks voretaq7. I'm currently looking into chef, and it seems to be doing what I need. I appreciate the help and pointing me in the proper direction instead of giving me a solution that would lead me down a more painful path later :-)